# Change namespace prefix

Tags: managed-package

I am creating a managed package. It has not yet been uploaded to AppExchange. Is it possible to change a namespace prefix since I have registered it?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible. Maybe SF support will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Workaround to get the code in another developer org and create new namespace there and then create new managed package.

Reference:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000060519&language=en_US